# Find control in ListView that inside a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ListView inside the Repeater and i like to retrieve the Id value from a tbl in repeater and assign it to a txtBox inside the ListView. My problem is i can not find controls in List view(which is inside the repeater control). (i am fairly new btw)

I get this(Object reference not set to an instance of an obj..) Just in case i like to make it clear once again, i have a repeater, and i have both table and listView in this repeater. So i want to retrieve the ID value from a table column as each item displayed in repeater and assign this individual ID to a control inside the ListView so i can attach and display the data by their primary.ID = FK.ID. I collect the ID from repeater items by "repeaterGetSelectedID" property and asign it to a label outside of the repeater just fine but i like to assign this ID value to a textbox which is inside the listView though i can not find controls in listView. Hope i've managed to explain. Thank you!!!!

Comment: post the markup of your repeater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the ItemDataBound event to access the repeater's controls:

```
protected void repeaterID_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        ListView listView = e.Item.FindControl("listViewID") as ListView;
        TextBox textBox = listView.FindControl("textBoxID") as TextBox;

        textBox.Text = listView.StringYoureLookingFor;
    }
}
```

Make sure to set the `OnItemDataBound` property of the repeater to "repeaterID_ItemDataBound" so the event actually gets fired when binding its data items.

Comment: Thanks, I used the above code and i still have this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. It indicates the txtBox in red color.

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using here?  Keep in mind that `listViewID` and `textBoxID` should be replaced with the actual IDs of your controls.  So if it's actually named listView1, then you need `FindControl("listView1")`.  The same goes for `StringYoureLookingFor` - that is just a placeholder for the value that you actually want to display.

Comment: Did you get this question answered?

Comment: I am so appreciated with this help of yours! I have changed the ListView with Gridview as necessity calls so i am still trying the above method to call the controls inside of the Gridview (in this case) i have found the GridView though not the label in it. It's in the itemtemplate of the Grid. Thanks

Comment: Updates: I thank you ever so much you got me a step closer to the solution though i got it with the 4eachloop so it's solved!!! Thank you!